# WebAPI Action Return :The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: asp.net-web-api

this is my sample web api action which return **The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.** when i am not passing any country code.

```
[HttpGet, Route("GetByID/{customerID}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetCustomer(string customerID)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage retObject = null;
            bool IsError = false;
            Customer customer = null;
            var message="";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerID))
            {
                 message = string.Format("Customer ID is empty or null");
                 HttpError err = new HttpError(message);
                 retObject = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);
                 retObject.ReasonPhrase = message;
                IsError = true;
            }
            else
            {
                customer = repository.Get(customerID);
                if (customer.CustomerID == null)
                {
                     message = string.Format("Customer with id [{0}] not found", customerID);
                     HttpError err = new HttpError(message);
                     retObject = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);
                     retObject.ReasonPhrase = message;
                     IsError = true;

                }
            }

            if (IsError)
                return retObject;
            else
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
        }
```

when i am calling **GetByID** without argument then i am not getting error message which i set in code. see my code and then must notice that i set error when customerID is empty or null but i am getting different error.

i set this error when customer id is null or empty.

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerID))
    {
         message = string.Format("Customer ID is empty or null");
         HttpError err = new HttpError(message);
         retObject = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);
         retObject.ReasonPhrase = message;
        IsError = true;
    }
```

so please guide me how could i return my error when customer id is not supplied when action called........any way exist. guide me where to change in my code as a result my error message should be return to client when customer id is null or empty. thanks

### UPDATE 1

this way issue has been sorted.

```
[HttpGet, Route("GetByID/{customerID?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCustomer(string customerID = null)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the parameter `customerID` defined as the required in the routing, so when it is not supplied the action is not found. Try using the `?` to mark the parameter as the optional one:

```
[HttpGet, Route("GetByID/{customerID?}")]
```

This way you will be able to handle the empty or null parameter within your action.